# The transparent pixels in my Bitmap shown as white

Tags: android, bitmap, ffmpeg, native-code, libyuv

I'm using c code to get `frame` from a gif file and it's working fine using `ffmpeg` library `av_read_frame`, then I convert the returned image from this format `BGRA to ARGB` format using this method `libyuv::ABGRToARGB`.

In the java part I receive the `bitmap` and when I put it in the `ImageView` the transparent pixels drawn white.

```
 Bitmap bitmap= Bitmap.createBitmap(150, 150, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
 getGifFrame(gifFile,bitmap); //native method which get image frame from gif file.
 imageTest.setImageBitmap(backgroundBitmap);//this bitmap in debug mode I can see that it has transparent pixels, but in drawn it appears white!
```

even when I loop on the returned `bitmap pixels` and check for each pixel I find them transparent!

```
          for (int x = 0; x < b.getWidth(); x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < b.getHeight(); y++)
                {
                    int color = b.getPixel(x, y);
                    if (color == Color.WHITE)//This condition never occurred 
                    {
                        b.setPixel(x, y, Color.TRANSPARENT);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Nothing happened and it's still white. Then I did convert all transparent pixels to TRANSPARENT !! and guess what, It's working!

```
else if (color == Color.TRANSPARENT)
{
  b.setPixel(x, y, Color.TRANSPARENT);
}
```

I don't understand why that happen. Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT 1:**
I get all pixels from the bitmap and set them again without doing anything and it worked also!?

```
  bitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
  bitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width,height);
```

Comment: Please show a screenshot and the XML layout.

Comment: Could it be that your background is simply white? Therefore it may look like a transparent pixel is white. This also explains your if statements

Comment: @DougStevenson Ok I'll do

Comment: @0xDEADC0DE thanks for your response. No my background is not white.

Comment: I don't have much knowledge of `ffmpeg` library but you mention the use of this function `libyuv::ABGRToARGB` while you try to convert BGRA to ARGB. I'm not sure if this is a problem, but you use a function to convert ABGR while you convert BGRA

Comment: @0xDEADC0DE I've just tried `libyuv::ABGRToARGB` but it changed the color of all pixels :D.